# Get the oldest row from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I coding a application that dealing with files. So, I have a table that contains information about all the files that registered in the application.

My "files" table looks like this: **ID**, **Path** and **LastScanTime**.

The algorithm that I use in my application is simple:

1. Take the oldest row (LastScanTime is the oldest)
2. Extract the file path
3. Do some magics on this file (takes exactly 5 minutes)
4. Update the LastScanTime to the current time (now)
5. Go to step "1"

Until now, the task is pretty simple. For this, I going to use this SQL statement for getting the oldest item:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM files ORDER BY [LastScanTime] ASC
```

and at the end of the item processing (preventing the item to be selected immediately again):

```
UPDATE Files SET [LastScanTime]=GETDATE() WHERE Id=@ItemID
```

Now, I going to add some complexity to the algorithm:

1. Take the 3 oldest row (LastScanTime is the oldest)
2. For each row, do:

   A. Extract the file path
   B. Do some magics on this file (takes exactly 5 minutes)
   C. Update the LastScanTime to the current time (now)
   D. Go to step "1"

The problem that now I facing with is that the whole process is going to be **processed in parallel** (no more serial processing). So, changing my SQL statement to the next statement is not enough!

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM files ORDER BY [LastScanTime] ASC
```

### **Why this SQL statement isn't enough?**

Let's say that I run my code and started to execute the first 3 items. Now, after a minute I want to execute another 3 items. This SQL statement will retrieve exactly the same "oldest" items that we already started to process.

### **Possible solution**

Implementing a SELECT & UPDATE (combined) that getting the 3 oldest item and immediately update their last scan time. Since there no SELECT & UPDATE in same statement, what will happens if between the executing of the first SELECT, will come in another SELECT? The both statements will get the same results. This is a problem... Another problem is that we mark the item as "scanned recently", before the scan is really finished. What happend if the scanned will terminated by an error?

I'm looking for tips and tricks to solve this problem. The solutions can add columns as needed.

I'll appreciate you help.

Comment: Do you have control over the table ? Can a column be added (ScanStatus)

Comment: I agree with @OguzOzgul . Add a column to keep track of things. When you start working on a file, mark it as `inProgress` in your DB. Then exclude all `Inrogress` columns from your "look for latest files" query. When you are done with a file, mark it as `InProgress = false`

Comment: You can even have a detail table to keep track of not only the current scans but also the scan history.

Comment: I have a tracking table. Each running process has an ID. So, I can add a new column to my "files" table - "ProcessId". Now, my SQL SELECT statement will filter out also files with ProcessId!=null. The only problem is that when I doing this select, I still don't have the process ID, since this process wasn't created yet!

Comment: You need an actual process ID when you update or insert a record, why would you need it during a select? UPDATE statements will cause locking of the table or row and if you don't specify (NOLOCK) hint with your SELECT statement, you will not get any dirty records (getting obsolete values of a row which is being updated)

Answer (score 0):

Well I usually have habit of having two different field name in the database. one is AddedDate and another is ModifiedDate. 
So the algorithm in your terms will be:-

1. Take the oldest row (AddedDate is the oldest)
2. Extract the file path
3. Do some process on this file
4. Update the ModifiedDate to the current time (now)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are going to invent event queue with your SQL. Possibly standard approaches like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ may solve your problem.